# Navbar items remain visible for some time after closing the collapsed navbar in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Navbar items remain visible for some time after closing the collapsed navbar as you can see in the second picture.
Html code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: transparent;>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Muhammad Yasir</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="my-1 mx-2 close">X</span>
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
.navbar-toggler>.close {
    display:inline;
    color: white;
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed>.close, .navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.navbar-toggler-icon {
    display:none;
}
```

Here is when I collapse the navbar[image]

And here is how collapsed item shows for some time even after closing the navbar[image]

For displaying collapsed navbar on the whole page and to change color on collapsing I have used some javascript along with css.
Javascript code:

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(){
$("nav").toggleClass("navbar-blue");
})
```

Css code:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    height: 100vh;
}
.navbar{
    color: white;
}
.navbar-blue{
    background-color: #23415C !important;
}
```

I don't know where is the problem in my code. I guess maybe its due to increased size of collapsing navbar.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] reproducing the problem. You didn't post anything that could be the cause of what you're describing, which makes it impossible for anyone to help you find the cause.

Comment: Sorry but I think that this cannot be explained further. As I asked a simple question that navbar items remain visible for some time after closing the collapsed navbar and I had provided all my code and screenshots of results(problem). What else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the JS to

```js
$(".navbar-toggler").on('click', function(e){
  $("nav").toggleClass("navbar-blue");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $($(e.target).closest('.navbar-toggler').data('target')).toggleClass('opened')
  }, 350);
})
```

... and add this to your CSS:

```js
.collapsing.opened {
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

See it working:

```js
$(".navbar-toggler").on('click', function(e){
  $("nav").toggleClass("navbar-blue");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $($(e.target).closest('.navbar-toggler').data('target')).toggleClass('opened')
  }, 350);
})
```

```css
.navbar-toggler>.close {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-toggler.collapsed>.close, .navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed)>.navbar-toggler-icon {
    display:none;
}


.navbar{
    color: white;
}
.navbar-blue{
    background-color: #23415C !important;
}

.collapsing.opened {
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
.navbar-collapse > .navbar-nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 58px);
}
.navbar-toggler>.close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
body {
  background-color: #212121 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: transparent;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Muhammad Yasir</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="close">X</span>
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Additionally,

```
.navbar-collapse > .navbar-nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 58px);
}
```

... fixes the opening animation of your collapse (removes the jump), and

```
.navbar-toggler>.close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

... combined with removing `mx-1 my-2` classes from it will stop your title from slightly changing position when closing/opening the `.navbar-collapse`.

---

Here's how the above works:

`.navbar-collapse`s animation is performed by swiftly adding `.collapsing` class to it (which gives it a `transition-duration` of `.35s`). Setting the duration to `0s` fixes the problem, but also disables the opening animation, as Bootstrap uses the same class for both opening and closing animations.
Had they used a different class for opening (say: `.expanding`),

```
.collapsing { 
  transition-duration: 0s 
}
```

... would have been sufficient.

That's why the solution is to toggle a custom class on the target element (`.opened`) 350ms after the toggler is pressed and only override the `transition-duration` value when both classes are present.

In theory, this method has the potential to break when one clicks very rapidly (more than once every 350ms) on the toggler button but, since it's an edge case and it involves complicating the solution considerably, I chose not to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. This had solved my problem but I have a slight issue that there is a lot of top and bottom space between each navbar item when it collapses.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really helped me a lot. I have solved the spacing issue by removing margin.